# Truncating html_safe text leaving unclosed tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm truncating some text like this:

```
<%= sanitize(post.body_text, tags: %w(p img)).truncate(20, :separator => " ").html_safe %>
```

The problem is if an img or p tag is caught in between 20 characters it cuts off like so:

```
<p>This is some text <img...
```

Which messes up the html of the rest of the page. So how do I truncate without leaving unclosed tags?

Comment: Oh, nice. No I haven't tried that but it's exactly what I need. Add that as an answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem before. Check out [this](https://github.com/hgmnz/truncate_html) gem